# Windows 10 wifi upload issue

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, upload

I'm having a really strange problem. I have a laptop running Windows 10 and having issues with uploading when on wifi.

Running any sort of speed test while on wifi yields 60+ Mbps download, then hangs on upload. Same laptop, wired (ethernet) yields same 60+ Mbps download, 3 Mbps upload.

Another laptop on the same wifi (running Windows 7 though) runs the whole speedtest just fine.

I'm at a loss. The wifi network is set as "private" on my Win10 laptop, I checked the firewall rules, even enabled the firewall log but can't see any dropped connections. Connections just seem to hang (for example my slack client's websocket times out trying to connect after 10 seconds).

Same laptop worked fine on my older router using 5Ghz. New router only has 2.4Ghz. I've seen this problem before at someone else's place, using 2.4Ghz network.

I tried turning off firewall, setting the network connection to not be 80211n, same negative result.

I'm running stock Windows firewall and Avast antivirus.

Any idea on where to look at?

EDIT: I tried a few more things. Using my phone's hotspot everything works fine. Also, it looks like the upload is actually being capped at 40 or 48K. Starts fast, then slows down.

Comment: So first You need to do is check if the QoS on the router is enabled, if yes, disable it and check again. If that is not the case, try to disable the encryption of the wi-fi and check again.

Comment: One of the QoS settings was on, but that's not it. I just ran the same speed test on my phone while connected to the same wifi and that one works fine too. There's no option to disable encryption on my router.

Comment: If you are sure that it isn't the QoS (You should disable it temporary for a quick test anyway), than the next possible thing that can mess things up is the encryption. There must be an option to disable it or at least something to set it to wpa (from wpa2) or tkip (from aes)

Comment: See my answer below, it was a driver issue. I had the latest from Dell, but apparently latest from Windows Update works better for Killer wifi...

Comment: I have a similar issue. Pls see http://superuser.com/questions/1023244/windows-10-wifi-connection-drops-throughput-issue

Answer (score 1):

Posting this maybe it helps someone in the future. I'm running a Killer wifi card on my laptop. Upgraded drivers from Dell site (laptop is an alienware) made no difference. However, going into the wifi adapter properties and doing Update Driver from there (which goes against the Windows drivers) did fix my problem.

I am amazed. I've never had that work before (Windows drivers were always older or more generic and not working). Live and learn.